# What is difference between RoboEarth and KnowRob?

Tags: theory

I am not able to clearly differentiate between the two platforms:

- [RoboEarth](http://roboearth.org/), and;
- [KnowRob](http://www.knowrob.org/).

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Aniruddha Singhal, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question. If you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you.

Answer (score 2):

[RoboEarth](http://roboearth.org/) was the name of a European project. [Knowrob is software](http://www.knowrob.org/knowrob) that was developed, in part, by the RoboEarth project.

Comment: Can you tell me about technical difference between there working? If there is any.

Comment: You misunderstand I think. RoboEarth is not software.

Answer (score 0):

Knowrob is the brainchild of the german computer scientist Michael Beetz who published the first paper in 2009, [KNOW ROB - Knowledge Processing for Autonomous Personal Robots](http://www.knowrob.org/_media/bib/tenorth09knowledge.pdf)
It uses a OWL-semantic-web (PDDL like) description for task modelling and a prolog interpreter to reach symbolic goals. Roboearth is a project from the netherlands (TU Delft) from same year 2009 to build a robotic cloud for sharing ressources [RoboEarth - connecting Robots worldwide](http://www.dct.tue.nl/RoboEarth/RoboEarth.pdf)